# Weird behaviour when using a normal map with a glossy node

Tags: materials, node-editor, normal-map

I tried to add a normal map on a glossy node but it gives a weird result.

[Here are some pictures to better explain the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77nfE.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know any fixes?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your normal map?

Comment: [Here](https://we.tl/hci3xjFVYN) _a.tga is the diffuse and _n.tga is the normal map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your normal map is just too strong. Turn down the strength:
[image]